# OpenCL: What type of memory to use?

Tags: memory, constants, local, opencl

I have some sort of filtering kernel, something like this:

```
__kernel void filterKernel (__global float4 *filter, __global float4* in_array, __global float4* out_array)
{
...
out_array[tid] = in_array[tid] * filter[fid];
...
}
```

- kernel filterKernel is called several times (about 1000 times).
- Variable *filter* is an array of floats that **never changes** it's values (stays the same for all work groups and for all kernel calls).
- in_array contains 32768 floats.

What's the best declaration of this variable *filter*? __constant? __local? Maybe placing a "const" here and there? What helps the compiler the most? What makes the code the fastest?

Comment: Has your question been answered ? If yes then please accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the constant address space (__constant), since most GPUs have special caches for constant memory. The only issue is that constant memory is small in size (in order of 16-64KBs).

Comment: In case I use constant memory: Should I add a define (e.g ___constant float4* filter = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...}; ) in my .cl file, or keep *filter* in my function interface and fill the array on the CPU before I call the function? Is there a difference at all?

Comment: @Frizz: Fill it from the CPU using clSetKernelArg.

Comment: This is way slower than filling the __constant array in the .cl file. See my comments below.

Answer (score 1):

__local would be wrong, since you can't initialize it to anything. You probably want to use __constant, provided that it will fit.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too large, try defining your *filter* globally inside the .cl file.
There you can try to allocate it either in the **__constant** or **__local** space and compare which one is faster. But not all SDKs support global variables in the __local address space (I am looking at you ATI).

If you still want to pass the filter as a kernel argument, consider calling its SetKernelArg(0, ...) only **once**. It is nor necessary to call SetKernelArg() 1000 times, as long as the value or the index of the kernel argument doesn't change. Although this might not have a measurable performance impact, it's still cleaner.

Comment: From all the various methods I've tried so far (constant memory, LDS, texture cache) defining it in the .cl file, as __constant, is by far(!) the fastest. Surprisingly there's a huge(!) difference between A) passing a __constant array via SetkernelArg() to the kernel before calling it - or B) defining the __constant array in the .cl file itself. Unfortunately method B) only works for ATI/AMD. Nvidia's OpenCL implementation is buggy here (I already reported this bug, will be fixed in CUDA 3.3).

Comment: Yes, i second that. The CUDA SDK is very buggy. I tried to implement a byte_swap() function inside the kernel using bit shifting operations. The OpenCL compiler recognizes the purpose of the function and tries to map it to a bswap32 resp. bswap64 instruction - which cannot be found or resolved...

Comment: Frizz: Have you checked the impact of setting the kernel argument for the __constant buffer only once vs. before every kernel enqueue?

Comment: No, I didn't check if this makes a difference. Will do. ... Usually I ONLY test how much time the clEnqueueNDRange() call takes to finish.

Comment: Checked: It makes no difference at all (setting __constant buffer kernel argument only once vs. before every kernel call). At least not on my hardware (GT240).